# How to update the response file in install4j outside of the installer

Tags: java, install4j

I have a few variables that are set by the user in a form on my install4j installer. The user also has the ability to update those variables from within a screen in my application. Is there a way to access the response file and update those values so that when an update runs the new values are automatically pulled in?

I tried to access the response file location using com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables but it couldn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the response file and update those values so
>   that when an update runs the new values are automatically pulled in?

Yes, that is possible. The default response file path relative to the installation directory is

```
.install4j/response.varfile
```